# Screen tearing without compiz

Tags: compiz, intel, openbox, tearing

I am trying to setup a working 13.04 desktop. If I use default ubuntu desktop, it loads compiz and I don't have any tearing.
If I run openbox, I get tearing while compiz is disabled.

Ive tried to add this in `/etc/enviornment`:

```
CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:disable-culling
```

But it didn't work. Also tried compton as a composite manager for openbox but also didn't have any luck.

In `xorg.conf` I have `TripleBuffer` set to on.

Would like to use openbox, i3wm, mate, xfce... everything except the default unity desktop.

Any help, please?

Comment: Oscar: did you try the second line in /etc/environment from this answer: http://superuser.com/a/603771/37734? This fixed my tearing problem.

Comment: What vid card? Proprietary Dirvers? More info please! if your using a Nvidia card the wait for V-sync option could cause ploblem, but it shouldn't... pastebin your xorg.conf this might help me figure out what is causing this